# Issue with MAX32664 breakout board from Protocentral on STM32L476RG Nucleo-64: Fixed SpO2 value

Tags: embedded, stm32, i2c, stm32-hal

I am working with an STM32L476RG Nucleo-64 MCU and MAX32664 breakout board from Protocentral connected via I2C.

Goal: To retrieve four values from the sensor: systolic BP, diastolic BP, heart rate, and SpO2.

I have developed a library for the MAX32664 sensor on STM32 by referring to the Arduino library provided by Protocentral.

Issue:

- While I successfully receive all four values from the sensor, the SPO2 value remains fixed.
- It shows either 0% (when my finger is not on the sensor) or 100% (when my finger is placed on the sensor).
- The other values (systolic blood pressure, diastolic blood pressure, and heart rate) show variation as expected.

Observations:

- I examined the contents of the FIFO buffer received from the sensor and noticed that the SPO2-related data are located at the 18th and 19th indices.
- However, the data at the 19th index does not change at every execution, leading to the fixed SPO2 value issue.

Troubleshooting steps taken:

- Tried uploading Protocentral's example code (Example2-BPT-estimation-mode) on STM32 via Arduino IDE. Encountered the same issue.
- Sensor works flawlessly with ESP32 using Protocentral's library.
- Data at the 19th index of the FIFO buffer changes dynamically on ESP32, suggesting STM32-specific issue.
- I suspect there might be an issue with the STM32 HAL library, but I'm uncertain.

Request for Assistance:

1. What could be causing this fixed SPO2 value issue on the STM32 platform?
2. How can I troubleshoot and debug this issue further?
3. Are there any specific considerations or configurations required in the STM32 HAL library when working with I2C sensors like the MAX32664?

Any insights or guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I would start with scope and check what is physically sent from the sensor to the MCU. You can't blame MCU or its software if it only displays what it actually received from the sensor device. So start there and verify that data from sensor actually varies when used with STM.

Comment: If you already have an Arduino library for the sensor, why don't you run the [Arduino Core for stm32](https://github.com/stm32duino/Arduino_Core_STM32)? It would be much easier than writing your own library, especially when you don't sound very familiar with STM32 HAL library and development environement.

Comment: @hcheung, Thank you for the prompt response. I have tried running the Arduino library code ([Example2-BPT-estimation-mode](https://github.com/Protocentral/protocentral-pulse-express/blob/master/examples/Example2-BPT-estimation-mode/Example2-BPT-estimation-mode.ino)) on the STM32, but the issue still persists.

Comment: Without your code and error log, we can't even speculate...

Comment: @hcheung, Regarding the Arduino library code, I used the example from Protocentral [Link](https://github.com/Protocentral/protocentral-pulse-express/tree/master/examples/Example2-BPT-estimation-mode) with added declarations for SDA and SCL pins on STM32
`#define SCL PB8`
`#define SDA PB9`
While there are no errors, the SpO2 value remains constant at 100%. I get systolic BP, diastolic BP and Heart Rate values correctly.
For the library I built, here is the code - [Link](https://gist.github.com/sirishhublikar/92f5a7ed0acb9578cb809b727452c8d6)

Comment: The value of `spo2` is a `float`, and you are using `printf("%.2f\r\n", max32664Output.spo2)` in your code, did you turn on the compiler option `-u _printf_float`? Right click on your project in STM32CubeIDE, click on "properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings ->MCU Settings" and tick "Use float with printf from newlib-nano(-u _printf_float)".

Comment: @hcheung, Yes, I have already enabled it.